# In JavaScript what is the right way to kill a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know that I can set it's style to "display: none"

However, that just hides it.

I really want to kill a DOM element and all of it's children.

The context is that I'm building a desktop-like GUI system (for learning purposes) inside of a DOM, and when a "window" is closed, I want that DIV and all it's children to be removed.

Thus, in JavaScript, how to I tell the GC "hey, get rid of this DOM element, it's no longer needed"?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove it from the DOM, let your reference get destroyed or fill it with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about removeChild ?

See http://dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/ for more information

Answer (score 1):

To remove all elements, I suppose you could set `element.innerHTML` to an empty string (although I've never tried it myself). Otherwise, you could use `element.removeChild(child)`, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.removeChild).

jQuery also supports `$([selector]).remove([selector])`, which is more flexible in specifying which elements you want to remove at once. There's more information about jQuery `remove` [here](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).